# Django Jquery/Ajax File Upload No File In POST

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

i am trying to work on uploading a csv to a django app.  The issue that i'm having is I can't seem to pass the file and be able to access it with my view.  There are no errors

form.py:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
   csv_file = forms.FileField()
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'ajax-view' %}" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileForm">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

js file:

```
// i've tried to add this as well passing file and data to the ajax
  var file;
  $('#id_csv_file').on('change', function(){
  file = event.target.files;
});

$('#fileForm').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData($('#fileForm').get(0));
  data.append('file', $('#id_csv_file')[0].files);

  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
      url: '/ajax/view',
      data: {'file': data},
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data) {

        // display the new data
        console.log(data)

      }
  });
```

});

My views are:

```
def view(request):
    form = FileUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', { 'form':form })

def ajax_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      print request.POST
      print request.FILES
```

the above prints just show: 

`<QueryDict: {}>
<MultiValueDict: {}>`

Comment: Change `data: {'file': data}`, to `data: data`. I think that should fix it.

Comment: that worked - thanks!